# Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting Support in .NET 5

Tags: visual-studio, .net-5

I am upgrading my .NET Framework 4.7.2 project to .NET 5 and am getting compatibility issues from the .NET portability analyzer for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` types. I have upgraded the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`, `MSTest.TestFramework`, and `MSTest.TestAdapter` packages and have re-targeted the project to .NET 5 but I am still having the same issues.

Is there an alternative to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` that is compatible with .NET 5?

Comment: See this guide on how to upgrade to MSTestV2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/mstest-update-to-mstestv2?view=vs-2019

Comment: My XML file is already targeting MSTestV2

Comment: Have you considered moving to xUnit instead ?  We've been using it with .net 5 and works like a charm.

Comment: @AlexM What errors are you getting? Show us your `.csproj` file please.